# Which versioning control system is using XTL files ? SW identification

Tags: version-control

I'm trying to identify versioning system by folder structure. I've got this project from our new customer and he has no idea about anything. I need help with software identification, so I can browse the sources. Repo struct. is as following:

[image: repo structure]

.index contains SQLite3 DB

There is a lot of .xtl files in within these folders. I tried Mercurial, but it's not Mercurial repo. Please help me with identification.

XTL file content example:

```
    <t:content lang="en-us" style="background-image:url('/svc/stream/media/coffee_strip');background-position:left top;background-size:auto;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-attachment:scroll;" styleClass="cover-and-fit fix-alt" xmlns:t="uri:t">

<div class="grid grid-gutter-large">
    <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="grid-col ice-container box-shadow grid-one-fifth" style="background-image: url(&quot;/svc/stream/media/paper_background&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-size: auto; background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="ice-content align-center small-padding-top small-padding-bottom">
                <t:link href="/en"><t:img height="100" src="/media/DC_logo_new" width="95"/></t:link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-col ice-container grid-four-fifths">       
            <div class="grid"><div class="grid-row"><div class="grid-col ice-container grid-three-fourths"><t:module class="Menu" function="display" styleClass="small-padding-top mini-margin-top align-center cs-inversed">
<t:prop name="root" value="auto"/>
<t:prop name="template" value="horizontal"/>
<t:prop name="style" value="clean"/>
<t:prop name="mobileTemplate" value="off-canvas-left"/>
<t:prop name="startlevel" value="1"/>
<t:prop name="maxdepth" value="0"/>
<t:prop name="mobileToggle" value="with-text"/>
<t:prop name="limit" value="none"/>
<t:prop name="fillAllSpace" value="false"/>
</t:module></div><div class="grid-col ice-container grid-one-fourth"><t:module class="product" function="myCart" styleClass="none-margin-bottom small-padding-bottom small-padding-top small-margin-top align-center cs-inversed"/></div></div></div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

</t:content>
```

Comment: I don't think it's SCM-related files , because https://fileinfo.com/extension/xtl "File type:
Vietcong Data File
Developer:
Pterodon
Category:
Game files
Vietcong (first-person shooter (FPS) video game that takes place during the Vietnam War) data file that is usually located within other game data files "

Comment: Well, that's just coincidence. Actually these XTL files really contains XML, which seems to be related to some IDE/Versioning soft.